# How can I update UIProgressVeiw in Swift3 on viewDidLoad() Method?

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I have created `UIProgressView` and `UILabel` programatically. I want my progressbar to get update every second and show the progress on screen and also update the label value. All of this should done on the call of `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: What did you try to accomplish this, or at least where did you start?

Comment: I am just learning Swift 3...so It is learning experiment for me.

Comment: I am sorry, I was only looking for a specific code from you, it's kind of a general agreement here on StackOverflow to show some code to get people started. Otherwise a question may become too general or too opinion-based.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a variable of type `Timer?`, then simply start your timer from your `viewDidLoad` method which will receive call after every one second.
Then simply update your `progressBar.progress` and `label.text` value in that method as mentioned below:

1. Take a variable

   ```
   var timer:Timer?
   ```
2. In your `viewDidLoad` use

   ```
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.updateProgressAndLabelValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   ```
3. Make a function and do the needful

   ```
   func updateProgressAndLabelValue(){
       //You will get call every second here
       //You can update the progressBar and Label here only
       //For example: yourProgressViewOutlet.progress = updatedValue
       //And lblYOuLabel.text = "\(updatedValue)"      
   }
   ```

Comment:    Thanks , i had problem in #selector ,,